# BeautifulSoup: TypeError: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working on this example of how to webscrape that I found on youtube and just going step by step through it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xQTJi2tqgk
Here is my code and the error I keep getting.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ('http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=coffee&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA')
r = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in links:
    print "<a href='%s'>%s</a>" %(link.get("href"), link.text)

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})

print g_data
```

ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 8, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (2 given)
```

I have tried to use the soup module on other files and it still won't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I ran your code myself and did not get an error.

Comment: Code looks fine. You should check your install of BeautifulSoup (version?)

Comment: Try `BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")`?

Comment: When I try BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser") I get the same error except that it says I've given 3 arguments. I'm working on PyCharm, is it possible that something got screwed up with the pydevd.py file?

Comment: what OS and python version are you using?

Comment: I'm using El Capitan and running Python 2.7.11.

Comment: I tried on windows 7, and works fine! (bs4 4.4.1 and requests 1.10.0)

Comment: Works for me on El Capitan and Python 2.7.10, I would say it's an issue with your PyCharm.